# EF Core 5 HasForeignKey Problem with Differing Column Name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Environment: .Net 5.0, EntityFrameworkCore 5.0, MS Sql Server

I've set up a one-to-many relationship in my database (using `HasForeignKey`), but when I try to access the parent record from the child using `.Include(x => x.Parent)` I get an invalid column name error. I've done this type of thing many times in the past, but it was always with the `Child` table having a property (and FK on said property) called `ParentTableName` + `Id`. In this case where it's failing, the property doesn't match that pattern.

So my question is: why is EF ignoring my Fluent API configuration? It seems to me that it shouldn't matter what the column is called if I've set up the relationship correctly (and the data types on each column match). Is there some additional step I need to take in the fluent api setup? See example below:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ForeignKeyName { get; set; } // This could say anything, just not "ParentId"
    
    [NotMapped] // Included so add-migration doesn't try to create a mapping, but when removed I get the same error
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

And my configuration

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasMany<Child>()
    .WithOne(x => x.Parent)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ForeignKeyName);
});
```

The usage that fails:

```
var children = _context.Children.Include(x => x.Parent).ToList(); // Says "Invalid Column Name 'ParentId'"
```

The foreign key is set up on the database already, but when I try to run add-migration it still suggests creating a) a new column on `Child` called `ParentId` (why?), b) an index on said column, and c) a foreign key using `ParentId`. I'd rather understand what's going on here than just change the property name and remain blissfully ignorant.

**EDIT**
Updating to make answer clear since comment thread is long. The key was to make sure that [NotMapped] is on both navigation properties, AND (in answer below) to have the fluent API reference the relationship in both directions (Parent to Child and Child to Parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code was tested in VS 2019. Data base with ForeignKeyName  ForeignKey was created successfully.

you have to fix the classes

```
public class Parent
{
   [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Child.Parent))]
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ForeignKeyName { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ForeignKeyName))]
    [InverseProperty("Children")]
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

or db context

```
          modelBuilder.Entity<Child>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.Parent)
                   .WithMany(p => p.Children)
                   .HasForeignKey(d => d.ForeignKeyName);
            });
```

you have to delete a previous Migrations folder and delete a previous database too. After  this make a clear migration using  Add-Migration InitialCreate. And after this use Update-Database.

Comment: These didn't work for me. The changes in the first code block didn't have any effect (same error message on the `Include` call); adding the second change (which I had tried prior and hoped would fix it) results in an error "Invalid column name ParentId1"; note the 1 in the name that EF sometimes tries to put on shadow properties. No clue why it wants a shadow property when it's  been told what property to use as the key.

Comment: @broccoli_rob you have to delete all your old db migration folder and old database
 . After this make new migration that will create a new db before trying to make new queries

Comment: Seems like a nuclear option, but even when doing that, the new migration file has this line: `migrationBuilder.RenameColumn(name: "ForeignKeyName", table: "Child", newName: ParentId1");`, and when table is being built for the first time it tries to create column "ParentId1", which indicates the same problem.

Comment: @broccoli_rob I just tested my code in VS 2019. Data base with ForeignKeyName  ForeignKey was created successfully.

Comment: Yea I'm getting right FK but also getting the new column ParentId, AND a FK on that property, and that seems to be the one that EF want's to use when running `Include`. Can I ask what version of EF Core you're using?
`migrationBuilder.CreateTable(name: "Child", columns: table => new { ForeignKeyName = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false), ParentId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true) // this shouldn't exist },`

Comment: @broccoli_rob I don' t have any extra columns. You have to copy paste my code, it seems that you are still doing something wrong. Check the db context again. Use seach (Ctrl-F)  to find any ParentId in your solution.  I am using net core 5 but it will be working at EF6 as well. I am answering a couple of questions like yours almost everyday, and everybody is happy.

Comment: Yea I got it to stop creating the erroneous columns (key was to include the [NotMapped] AND the second fluent API line you mentioned), but now the `Include` call throws another error, `Expression {} is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access`. That's a separate error from the title of this thread though so I'll try to solve it elsewhere. Thanks

Comment: @broccoli_rob It is hard to work with you since you don' t follow the answer.  You have to clean everything else, leave only what is in my answer. You shouldn't post the question if you don't need the answer.

Comment: I did follow your answer I even referenced it in my edit to make it clear.

Comment: Does not work. I configured navigation and HasForeignKey() on both ends of the relationship, and Code-First still creates an additional FK column "<parent_entity><parent_pk>" on the child table. The only difference is that this extra column is nullable. EF Core 7, VS 2022, latest versions.